# SwiftUI - avoid AnyPublisher the first time

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've created publishers to validate the user input, in this case just validate they have 32 chars length.

ConnectionVM

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class ConnectionVM: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    //INPUT
    @Published var uuid1: String = ""
    @Published var uuid2: String = ""
    //OUTPUT
    @Published var uuid1Message = ""
    @Published var uuid2Message = ""
    
    init() {
        isUUID1ValidPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { valid in
                valid ? "" : "UUID1 must have 32 characters"
            }
            .assign(to: \.uuid1Message, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
        
        isUUID2ValidPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { valid in
              valid ? "" : "UUID2 must have 32 characters"
            }
            .assign(to: \.uuid2Message, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
    
    private var isUUID1ValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
      $uuid1
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { input in
          return input.count == 32
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    private var isUUID2ValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
      $uuid2
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { input in
          return input.count == 32
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    private var isFormValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
      Publishers.CombineLatest(isUUID1ValidPublisher, isUUID2ValidPublisher)
        .map { uuid1IsValid, uuid2IsValid in
          return uuid1IsValid && uuid2IsValid
        }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

ConnectionView

```
import SwiftUI

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

struct ConnectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ConnectionVM()
//    @State var uuid1: String = ""
//    @State var uuid2: String = ""
    @State var authenticationDidFail: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            WelcomeText()
            LogoImage()
            UUIDTextField(uuid: $viewModel.uuid1)
            if !viewModel.uuid1Message.isEmpty {
                Text(viewModel.uuid1Message)
                .offset(y: -10)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            UUIDTextField(uuid: $viewModel.uuid2)
            if !viewModel.uuid2Message.isEmpty {
                Text(viewModel.uuid2Message)
                .offset(y: -10)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("Button tapped")
            }) {
               LoginButtonContent()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight*0.5)
    }
    struct WelcomeText : View {
        var body: some View {
            return Text("Welcome!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
        }
    }
    struct LogoImage : View {
        var body: some View {
            return Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(150)
                .padding(.bottom, 75)
        }
    }
    struct UUIDTextField : View {
        @Binding var uuid: String
        var body: some View {
        return TextField("UUID", text: $uuid)
                    .padding()
                    .background(lightGreyColor)
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
    }
    struct LoginButtonContent : View {
        var body: some View {
            return Text("LOGIN")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(15.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConnectionView()
    }
}
```

The problem is the first time when the screen is just opened, the error messages appear automatically.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but note that `.assign(to: \.uuid1Message, on: self)` may produce a strong reference cycle.

Comment: @pawello2222 Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Ricardo Take a look at [Does ‘assign(to:)’ produce memory leaks?](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546) A workaround is to use `.sink` with a `[weak self]`

Answer (score 0):

You basically need another condition to guard whether to display the message.

That condition could be that the field has first changed, so you'd count the number of times each field has changed, and produce a Bool on whether it has changed more than once (i.e. beyond the initial assignment of `""`)

```
let hasUUID1Changed = $uuid1.scan(0, { a, _ in a + 1}).map { $0 > 1 }
let hasUUID2Changed = $uuid2.scan(0, { a, _ in a + 1}).map { $0 > 1 }
```

`Publishers.Scan` acts as the counter / accumulator in this case. The lifetime would be the lifetime of the view model.

Then you could use this publisher in combination with the `isUUID1ValidPublisher` to determine whether to display the message:

```
isUUID1ValidPublisher
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .combineLatest(hasUUID1Changed) // here
    .map { (valid, changed) in
        valid && !changed ? "" : "UUID1 must have 32 characters"
    }
    .sink { [weak self] self?.uuid1Message = $0 }
    .store(in: &cancellableSet)
```